# env-cmd Error: Failed to find .env file at path

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

can anyone help me with .env-cmd issue?

env-cmd Error: Failed to find .env file at path: .env.development at getEnvFile C:\Users\Jake\project\fcmanager-frontend\node_modules\env-cmd\dist\get-env-vars.js

package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "start-prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
    "build-prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development react-scripts build",
    "start-prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.production react-scripts start",
    "build-prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.production react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

After the certain version for env-cmd, they ask you to add -e be

```
   "start-dev": "env-cmd -e dev react-scripts start",
    "build-dev": "env-cmd -e dev react-scripts build",
    "start-local": "env-cmd -e local react-scripts start",
    "build-local": "env-cmd -e local react-scripts build",
    "start-prod": "env-cmd -e prod react-scripts start",
    "build-prod": "env-cmd -e prod react-scripts build",
```

Comment: try -e instead of -f

Answer (score 1):

There can be an additional problem cause. If you're using `.env-cmdrc` make sure that you haven't missed any commas and your file structure corresponds to the JSON structure

Comment: comma to the end of the last line in a json format.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an empty file called .env.local beside package.json file.

The file need to be in the outer layer.

Answer (score 0):

I try with this ->
`env-cmd -f [path of dev.env] nodemon src/index.js` and it works.

- "start-dev": "env-cmd -e ./dev react-scripts start",
- "build-dev": "env-cmd -e ./dev react-scripts build"